# "#using-proxy-artist".format(orig_handle) with Pie Chart(data from CSV) Matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

After adding a legend in a pie chart, I got a UserWarning:

```
UserWarning: Legend does not support '47036560' instances.
A proxy artist may be used instead.
```

I want to add legend to show memory status used and free memory from my csv file.

***csv file :***

```
USED;FREE

26932440;47036560
```

***my code :***

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['text.color'] = 'k'

data = np.loadtxt('show-flash.csv' ,dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0, 1)).astype(str)
slice = data[1]
labels = data[0]
colors = ['lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
explode = [0.05, 0]
plt.pie(slice, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, startangle=90, shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')

plt.title('Show Flash\n(Bytes)')
plt.legend(slice,labels)
plt.show()
```

I need the output like this pic:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is a warning saying that you cannot use a string as a legend handle. The `handles` supplyied to `plt.legend(handles, labels)` must be matplotlib artists. The easiest way to obtain those artists are from the call to  `plt.pie()`.

```
pie = plt.pie(...)
plt.legend(pie[0], labels)
```

Complete example:

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = u"""USED;FREE

26932440;47036560"""

s = io.StringIO(d)

data = np.loadtxt(s ,dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0, 1)).astype(str)

slices = data[1]
labels = data[0]
colors = ['lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
explode = [0.05, 0]
pie = plt.pie(slices, labels=labels, colors=colors, explode=explode, startangle=90, 
              shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')

plt.title('Show Flash\n(Bytes)')
plt.legend(pie[0],[" ".join(a) for a in zip(labels, slices)])
plt.show()
```

producing

[image]

Comment: can we add a new variabel in legend?
on your code there's have 2 variabel (pie and labels), can i add a new variabel, so in legend there's have 3 variabel to show?
i exactly need the output legend like my example, that have colors,label,and slice

Comment: its worked like what i want, thanks for the answer :)